# dism unmount with commit on offline image and changes are still in pending status when remounted

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, wim, dism

Using dism to disable features in a offline Windows 2008 R2 wim image, executing cmd dism commands below:

Before any changes:

```
ServerCore-WOW64                                            | Enabled
then feature is set to diabled:
ServerCore-WOW64                                            | Disable Pending
```

But when using the exact same commands to mount the wim again the feature is still in state:

```
ServerCore-WOW64                                            | Disable Pending
```

Am I missing something regarding, dism and offline wim images? One thought is that it only goes to state Disabled in a online scenario, which seems a bit unlogical but stranger things have been implemented in process flows before. Any ideas is appreciated.

```
dism /Mount-WIM /WimFile:E:\images\windows2k8r2\w2k8r2\sources\install.wim /index:6 /MountDir:D:\images\windows2k8R2\w2k8r2_dsim

dism /Image:D:\images\windows2k8R2\w2k8r2_dsim /scratchdir:E:\images\scratchdir /Get-Features /Format:Table

*dism /Image:D:\images\windows2k8R2\w2k8r2_dsim /scratchdir:E:\images\scratchdir /Disable-Feature /FeatureName:ServerCore-WOW64

dism /Commit-Wim /MountDir:D:\images\windows2k8R2\w2k8r2_dsim /scratchdir:E:\images\scratchdir

dism /Unmount-WIM /MountDir:D:\images\windows2k8R\w2k8r2_dsim /scratchdir:E:\images\scratchdir /Commit
```

Command with * can also be execute by command line below, not sure about the difference?

```
dism /Image:D:\images\windows2k8R2\w2k8r2_dsim /scratchdir:E:\images\scratchdir /Disable-Feature:ServerCore-WOW64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the correct behaviour for some components as they have both offline/online scenarios to complete.

So not actually a problem.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/df5a562f-e0da-4db2-83c7-cb63e3ba1b1c/

FYI
True the windows setup will disable the 32-bit sub system support, but is as easy solvable with dism /online when the server is online. Also it won't remove the 32-bit sub system files/registry - just disable the support. So not entirely 100% satisfied for a 64-bit OS.